# Why do I need to use keyword "this" to call my enclosing methods or variables

Tags: java, nested-class

I have a doubt if I have a non-static nested class why do I need to use the keyword "this" to call a method or variable of my enclosing class?
What I think is the following: if a non-static nested class can access to methods and variables of its enclosing class and a non-static nested object instance is already associated to  its enclosing object instance why do I need to use "this"?
For example I have the following code:

```
public class ClassA {

    public class ClassB {

        public void bye() {
            ClassA.this.hello();
            // Why not just ClassA.hello()?
        }
    }

    public void hello() {

    }
}
```

and if from a method of my enclosing class I want to call a method of one of mine non-static classes how should I do?For example if from my method hello() I want to call bye() how should I type?

Comment: You can just type hello(). Without this keyword there would be an ambiguity with static methods of an outer class.

Comment: The definition is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you can simply call `hello()`.

`ClassA.hello()` would look for a static method named `hello()` in ClassA. `ClassA.this.hello()` looks for an instance method.

Comment: Thank you! if from a method of my enclosing class I want to call a method of one of mine non-static classes how should I do?For example if from my method hello() I want to call bye() how should I type?

Comment: @antox You need to call it on an instance of the inner class, for example `new ClassB().bye()`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this case where both the inner and outer class have a method with the same signature, you need to be able to distinguish which one to call:

```
 public class ClassA {

    public class ClassB {

        public void hello(){
          System.out.println("Hello b!);
        }
    }

    public void hello() {
       System.out.println("Hello a!);
    }
 }
```

What would happen if you call **hello()** from classB? You get Hello b!

What would happen if you call **this.hello()** from classB? You get Hello b!

These two are equivalent.

What about calling **ClassA.hello()** from classB? You get an exception, there is no *static* method called hello() declared.

But if you call **ClassA.this.hello()** from classB? You get Hello a! This is the syntax for acquiring reference to the outer class from the inner class, should they both have a method with the same signature, otherwise it would be kinda redundant to use this syntax, as inner classes already have access to the outer classes methods.

Comment: But the question is why `ClassB.hello()` does not suffice

Comment: that is the syntax for calling a static method. But there is no static method called hello() declared

Comment: You need not type `this.hello()` to call a non-static method called `hello()` in normal classes.

Comment: You are correct. But this case comes up when you have an inner class and an outer class that both have method with the same signature. This is where it is important to be able to choose which one to call.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassA.hello()` would work if `hello()` were declared as `static`.  But because it is an *instance* method, it needs to be called on an instance.

The `ClassA.this` syntax is called a *qualified `this`* in [JLS 15.8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4), and is the only way to refer to the `this` instance of an enclosing type.